# Whitelist not working for ingress-nginx controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Whitelisting is not working. Here is my ingress yaml file.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: testing
  namespace: testing
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "1.1.1.1/8"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: testing.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```

After creating that ingress resource, I can still access the nginx website even though my IP is not included in the whitelist.

Comment: What is the `ingress-nginx` version?

Comment: It is using this version of ingress nginx controller:

`quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.10.2`